Does android copy the camera frame data to java heap when addCallbackBuffer and setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer called?
As we know, android camera API can provide image data in 2 ways.

use setPreviewTexture to send data to an sufaceTexture with oes texture.
use setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer and  addCallbackBuffer , then we can get data from java arrays created by app.

In way 1, camera data go to GPU directly without copy.(may be not right,just I think)
In way 2, camera data will do copy and go to java heap.(may be not right,just I think)
Also we even can use the 2 ways together.(I once used them together in my project)
I am not sure that is there any data copy behavior when we use way 2. and how to avoid it?
And I also want to know where the camera store the image data underneath?

@fadden Can you explain it?
